# Post json receive null for parameter

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services, xsd

I am currently creating an apps in rest (in order to improve my skills in this domain). To be honnest I was working with jsp and servlet a long time ago but now I can see that json on a rest api is the new way of working. So I said why I won't do it.
First I am working wuth my old app server Tomcat (I love this cat). I followed what I saw in http://www.lessonslab.com/building-restful-webservices-using-apache-cxf/150/

It is really nice and I was able to produce a GET service and even a POST service easily. However in the POST method I receive a null object. Here is what I have.

In my beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bdproject.*" />

<jaxrs:server id="createAccount" address="/createAccount">
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="ProfileCXFServiceImpl" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
</jaxrs:server>

<bean id="ProfileCXFServiceImpl" class="com.bdproject.cxfrestservice.ProfileCXFServiceImpl"/>
```

Then here is my profileCxf

```
package com.bdproject.cxfrestservice;

    import javax.jws.WebService;
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    /**
     *
     * @author lessonslab.com
     * This is interface for the employee services
     *
     */
    @Path("/")
    @WebService(name="createAccount", targetNamespace="")
    public interface ProfileCXFService
    {

      @POST
      @Path("/createAccount")
      @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      public Response createAccount(@QueryParam("CreateAccountRQ") Request createAccountRQ);

    }
```

and now my impl:

```
        package com.bdproject.cxfrestservice;

    import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    public class ProfileCXFServiceImpl implements ProfileCXFService{

      @Override
      public Response createAccount( Request createAccountRQ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
      }

    }
```

You can see that ny impl is pretty empty :)

I am using Postman which is working well when I am doing a GET. For the post I receive a null object.

```
    {
  "CreateAccountRQ": {
    "-xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation": "schema.xsd",
    "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "ProfileInformation": {
      "-ProfileID": "String",
      "-Name": "String",
      "-Surname": "text",
      "Personnal": {
        "Contacts": {
          "Contact": [
            {
              "-Type": "String",
              "-Name": "String",
              "PhoneContact": {
                "Description": {
                  "-Value": "4545454554",
                  "-AreaCode": "06",
                  "-OverseaCode": "+33"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "AccountInformation": {
      "emailAddress": "String",
      "Password": "String"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried a lot of things like:

```
    @POST
@Path("/createAccount")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createAccount(@PathParam("CreateAccountRQ") Request createAccountRQ);
```

When I am debugging the object I am receiving is null which is pretty anoying to create an account :) 
I searched a lot to arrive at that point without asking question but now I am blocked for several hours for nothing :( maybe you will have a global view to say me that I was doing a crappy thing somewhere as for the post I did not find any tuto and I did everything like we are saying it in french "a taton" meaning " grope along"

Thanks a lot in advance and I hope that you will find a simple solution to this problem :)

Comment: So I made a mistake. In fact:
The create accountMethod must be 
`public Response createAccount(CreateAccountRQ createAccountRQ);`
CreateAccountRQ is an object with an ! @XMLRootElement
I was able to make it work with a simple object. But with this one it seems that I still receive null. I continue my investigation

Answer (score 0):

It is ok. I found the solution.
In fact I removed the parameter and changed the json by removing the first letter in UPPER case and took only what is inside CreateAccountRQ